# Kusto explorer - Not responding mode

Tags: json, azure, azure-data-explorer, adx, kusto-explorer

We are ingesting telemetry data into ADX, where one of the column in a table stores Nested Json where each cell contains 8000+ lines of JSON.

In Kusto explorer, after querying that table data for example "take 10" then when I click on that cell which has nested JSON value, the entire Kusto Explorer is going into Not Responding mode,

next I need to kill the session and reopen always. Do we have any solution for this kind of issue.

Comment: This may point to a bug in the application. Can you please share a JSON content and we (Kusto team) will check this.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Kusto.Explorer is a rich desktop application that enables you to explore your data using the Kusto Query Language in an easy-to-use user interface.

Below document contains steps which will help you in checking missing or corrupted system files.

[Kusto.Explorer](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/use-the-system-file-checker-tool-to-repair-missing-or-corrupted-system-files-79aa86cb-ca52-166a-92a3-966e85d4094e)

You can also reset the Kusto.Explorer. Follow this [MS Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/tools/kusto-explorer-troubleshooting) that describes how to progressively reset Kusto.Explorer.